# How to get 'Step' name by using Cucumber with Java to use in Extent report

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I want to use Step name which is mentioned in Scenario/Scenario Outline feature file. So please help me how to get the step information in Cucumber java.

Comment: Can u add some relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hooks to get the scenario object and then its name.
Should be something like this

```
package util;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

public class Hooks {
    public String scenario_name;
    @Before
    public void getScenario(Scenario){
        scenario_name = Scenario.getName();
    }
}
```

and then, don't forget to add util, in that case, to your glue

```
@CucumberOptions(...glue = {"yourStepPackage","util"}...)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @AleT, Thanks for reply. I want to get Step information which we write inside Sceanrio/ScenarioOutline, not scenario name.